# Creating an edit form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest, http

I am trying to create an edit from in my angularjs application but I am having some difficulty.  I just do not know how to go about it.

This is the state that takes you to the form:

```
ui-sref="system.institutions.edit({ id: i.id })"
```

Now when the form loads I did this:

```
<form role="form" name="editInstitutionForm" ng-submit="editInstitution()" ng-init="getInstitutionInfo()">
  ...
</form>
```

The function `getInstitutionInfo()` is supposed to load the data from the server into the individual form fields.

This is the function:

```
$scope.getInstitutionInfo = function() {

    InstService.show()
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.institutionInfo != undefined)
            {
                $scope.institutionInfo = data.institutionInfo;
            }
        })

};
```

This is the **show** method in my service:

```
InstService.show = function() {

    var url = '/api/v1'+window.location.pathname;
    url.replace('#', '');

    return $http
        .get(url)

};
```

Now my problem is how to pass the **id** from the **state** in the view through my **controller** to my **http service**.

Comment: Use the $stateParams service to get the state parameters. Pass the ID as argument InstService.show(). https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

Comment: Thank you, your comment was helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $stateParams to access the id you are providing in the transition to the state here: `ui-sref="system.institutions.edit({ id: i.id })"`

Example:

```
.controller('InstEditCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, InstService) {

    var id = $stateParams.id;

});
```